# Length of line segment at intersection of three spheres

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, spheres

For laying out a grid of spheres, I need to calculate the the length of the line segment (highlighted in red) at the intersection of three spheres:

[image]

Each sphere has an equal radius and is centred on the corners of an equilateral triangle; the $y$-coordinate for each sphere's center is $0$.

**So, my question is:** given the radius and $z$ and $x$ coordinates of each sphere, how do I calculate the length of the line segment highlighted in red?

Comment: Taking projection on plane should help.

Comment: @zkutch sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to explain to me?

Comment: Taking projection in perpendicular direction of red segment keep its length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image][image]

It is clear from the sketch that the segment is along line passing through the centroid of the $\triangle ABC$ and parallel to $z$-axis. Now, let $E$ be one end of the segment, $F$ be the centroid of the triangle. Hence, in $\triangle EFB$, by Pythagoras theorem, $$EB^2=EF^2+FB^2$$ The length of the segment is $2EF$.

In the question we are given the $x$ and $z$ coordinates of the respective centers. We get the coordinates of the centroid $F$ of the $\triangle ABC$ as $$F=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3},0,\frac{z_1+z_2+z_3}{3}\right)$$ Now, from this you get $BF$.

[Here](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/hzdjwnzp) is the figure drawn in Geogebra of the situation.

Comment: I gather I need to figure out the intersection of the line that is perpendicular to the plane of the triangle, passes through the triangle center and one of the circles, to find the coordinates of point $E$?

Comment: I did't understand your question. You want the coordinates of $E$, right?

Comment: Yes, to apply the Pythagoras theorem, I would nee the coordinates of $E$

Comment: @Jacco, I've edited the solution. Let me know if there is still any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. You added the part about finding $F$, but how do I find $E$?

Comment: Once you've got $FE$ by Pythagoras theorem, $x$ and $z$ coordinates of $E$ will be same of that of $F$ and the $y$ coordinate will be the length $EF$.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $(x,y,z)$ in the system of equations
$$\begin{align*}
r_1^2 &= (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 + (z-z_1)^2\\
r_2^2 &= (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 + (z-z_2)^2\\
r_3^2 &= (x-x_3)^2 + (y-y_3)^2 + (z-z_3)^2
\end{align*}$$

In your case you already know $y_1=y_2=y_3=0$, so it may be useful to solve for $y$.

In nondegenerate cases it will have 0, 1 or 2 solutions. In the last case you can then calculate the distance.